# nautilus hangs the whole ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, crash

when i click the icon of nautilus, the whole system will be down immediately.

don't tell me to try any shortcuts as I tried most of the shortcuts.
The only shortcut works is `alt`+`PrtScr`+`B` to reboot.

I'd tried to remove nautilus and reinstalled it again. It still doesn't work.

this's the second time it happened to me. I already reinstalled once.